# Free doesn't free pointers sent as a va_arg list

Tags: c, linux, variadic-functions

I want to free a variable list of pointer with the freeS macro below: freeS(s1,s2,...);

My code doesn't free the first pointer despite getting a print with the first pointer address from the freeSF function.
In main, free(s1) works but it should. free(s2) in main crashes as expected.

How can I free the s1 pointer in the freeSF function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define freeS(...) freeSF("", __VA_ARGS__, NULL)
void freeSF(char *paramType, ...) {
    va_list pl;

    va_start(pl, paramType);
    paramType = va_arg(pl, char *);
    while (paramType) {
        printf("arg %p\n", paramType);
        free(paramType);
        paramType = va_arg(pl, char *);
    }
    va_end(pl);
}

int main(int ARGC, char** ARGV) {
    char *s1 = strdup("1");
    char *s2 = strdup("2");
    printf("s1 %p, s2 %p\n", s1, s2);
    freeS(s1, s2);
    free(s1);
}
```

Comment: You are doing: `freeS(s1, s2)` then doing `free(s1)`. You are double freeing.  http://ideone.com/shZ3Sc works just fine. How do you know it isn't freeing?

Comment: When a pointer is double, there is an error: Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000024c5030. It happens only for free(s2)

Comment: It doesn't cause an error: http://ideone.com/2sQPXl  You are still calling `free` twice and that is undefined behaviour.. Don't call `free(s1)` and `free(s2)` when you are already doing `freeS(s1, s2)`..

Comment: That doesn't mean you're freeing a pointer to type double, it means you're calling free on the same pointer twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program exhibits [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you are double freeing.

With undefined behavior, anything can happen.  Your program may crash, it may output strange results, or (in this case) it may appear to work properly.  Adding a seemingly unrelated change, such as a call to `printf` or adding an unused local variable, can change the way undefined behavior manifests itself.

In this case, calling `free(s1)` in `main` isn't causing a crash.  It's still undefined behavior.  For example, when I run this code it doesn't crash.  But if I add a call to `malloc` just before calling `free(s1)`, it does crash.

Just because the code **can** crash doesn't mean it **will**.

Comment: Correct, I was writing the same, but I was thinking why doubling `free(s1)` in main causes error while with the OP code doesn't. Have you got an idea about it?

Comment: @LPs; That's the definition of undefined behaviour in itself. OP's code MAY or MAY-NOT cause an error. It is undefined. It might work for him, it might not.

Comment: @Brandon Well, I know.... Just out of curiosity: if this UB has an explainable behavior.

Comment: @LPs; If it has no defined behaviour, it can't really be explained. It can behave in many different ways. It might crash now, it might crash hours from now, it might never crash, it might work for you, it might not. It might work for me, it might not. We don't actually know how it will behave so we can't explain it. If it is observed, it may change ;). Undefined has no logic, no specific explanation. I mean we can explain it and say: "If you do X, something bad will happen" but that's about it.